# What is similar function in snowflake for REGEXP_EXTRACT function in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, regex, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Bigquery :

```
SELECT *,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(AM_EMAIL, '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+') as x_ALIAS,
    "https:" AS COL1
FROM `agm-data-.global_i.P_ROUTING`;
```

Want to Convert this bigquery into Snowflake ,Please suggest on REGEXP_EXTRACT Bigquery similar function in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake you would use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`. The regex you are using should work just fine, so:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(AM_EMAIL, '^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+') as x_ALIAS
```

Note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can also be expressed as `[:alnum:]`, so:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(AM_EMAIL, '^[[:alnum:].+-]+') as x_ALIAS
```